# How to run windows executables from terminal without the explicitly specifying the .exe extension?

Tags: zsh, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

As the title says most of the question, how can we run windows executables without specifying the explicit `.exe` suffix at the end.

[image]

For example reducing the call like `explorer.exe .` to `explorer .`, or `notepad.exe file` to `notepad file`, or `docker.exe ps` to `docker ps`, etc.

I was wondering is there's native way to do so, or is there a way to handle the `command not found` error and redirect to a `.exe` executable if no linux program are available in `$Path` with the command name.

**Edit:**

I forgot to add the environment previously, here it is:

- Terminal: Windows Terminal
- Linux: Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
- Shell: zsh
- OS: Windows 10 1909

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your system is more clearly. I am guessing you are using Windows and the Linux Subsystem, but you need to state this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the idea given by @DavidG. I have made this, hopefully this will make someone's day :)

The following script will create missing directory, symlinks for all the executables in windows if it does not exists:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/zsh

mkdir -p $HOME/.windows_binaries
cd $HOME/.windows_binaries

for ext in $( echo ${PATHEXT-".com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh;.msc"} | tr \; ' ' ); do
  for command in ${(M)commands:#*$ext}; do
    if [ -f $(basename $command $ext) ]; then; else
      ln -s $command $(basename $command $ext)
    fi
  done
done
```

And then we can append the `~/.windows_binaries` folder into the path so if no linux executable found, windows executable will be triggered:

In `$HOME/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.windows_binaries
```

Explaination of the above script:

- `#!/usr/bin/zsh` - Shebang that will redirect the script to be executed by zsh, because we did used a filter command that is not available in bash by default.
- `mkdir -p $HOME/.windows_binaries` - If the path does not exist, then create it :)
- `cd $HOME/.windows_binaries` - Change cwd to it
- `for ext in $(...); do` - Loop through each of the extension that is considered as script in the windows
- `for command in ${(M)commands:#*$ext}; do` - `$commands` indexes all the commands that can be used in the current shell, and using zsh filter we filter the command which ends with `$ext` extension.
- `if [ -f $(basename $command $ext) ]; then; else` - skip if command's symlink without the extension has been created, else continute to create a symlink with `ln -s`.

#### Edit:

Thanks to @user414777, for helping in optimizing the script. Now it does it in about 2-3x faster speed (7-9s):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/zsh

mkdir -p $HOME/.windows_binaries
cd $HOME/.windows_binaries

all_exts=${${${PATHEXT-".com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh;.msc"}//;/|}//./}
IFS=$'\n'

if [ $ZSH_VERSION ]; then setopt sh_word_split; fi

for command in $(whence -psm "*.($all_exts)"); do
  sym_name=${${command##*/}%.*}
  if [ -f $sym_name ]; then; else
    ln -s $command $sym_name
  fi
done
```

I also got to understand that the shell substitution for regex-replace / changes to string are better than piping it to some command like `tr`. And that IFS is not directly used to expand the substitution directly in zsh, we have to configure it before hand.

Comment: Why are you using `ln -s file .` + `mv file file.exe` instead of just `ln -s file file.exe`? Why are you using `for ext in $(echo some_expansion)` instead of just `for ext in some_expansion`? For something as simple as creating symbolic link to a list of files into a directory, this tries to do it in a very convoluted way. What about: `(DST=/some/dir; IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(whence -psm '*.(exe|bat)'); do ln -vs $f $DST/${${f##*/}%.*}; done)`

Comment: @user414777 thanks for the suggestion, I was using the echo, because the `;` was not getting separated by using `IFS=';'`. Your code is great example as well, appreciate the help (as being less experienced in shells learn something new) :)

Comment: I may have messed up something, but that rather sounds like a bug in zsh; why is it including them in the output of `whence -m`?

Comment: And I don't understand why it tries to create the link in `/mnt/c/Windows/...`, since in my example the last argument of `ln -s` starts with `$DST` => `/NOT/mnt/c/Windows`

Comment: @user414777 ye, I found that we have to manually specify to split the words by `IFS` in zsh. And I've done a mistake in creating symlink. Now it works seamlessly, thanks for the response now its very well optimized (I've added it as an edit) :)

Answer (score 7):

You can set up a [`command_not_found_handler`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#index-command_005fnot_005ffound_005fhandler). Untested:

```
function command_not_found_handler {
  for ext in ${(s:;:)${PATHEXT-".com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh;.msc"}}; do
    if (( $+commands[$1$ext] )); then
      exec -- "$1$ext" "${@:2}"
    fi
  done
  print -ru2 "command not found: $1"
  return 127
}
```

Note that this is specifically if `foo.exe` (or other extension such as `.bat`) works but you want to be able to type just `foo`. If `foo.exe` doesn't work in zsh but `foo` works in cmd and invokes a program called `foo.exe`, you have a different problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have proposed an edited your extension expansion code a bit, because it was not getting splitted in my case (It was just getting interpreted as the raw string like written there). I fired up a subshell and replaced the semicolon with space, if you have a more optimized version of doing this you can edit this again :)

Comment: For bash version of `command_not_found_handler`, see https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2003#issuecomment-618655416

Answer (score 5):

You have three options.

1. Always type the `.exe`.  Command completion might help, assuming your shell has it.  But this is what you are trying to avoid.
2. The alias solution already pointed out by others.
3. Make symbolic links without the .exe to the Windows executables.  These should be placed in a directory (on a Unix/Linux filesystem) in your path.  (You might want to add a directory to your path just for these.)  I would probably do this by:

   ```
   cd ~/bin.windows_exes
   ln -s /path/to/windows/executables/*.exe .
   prename 's/.exe$//' *.exe
   ```

   (`prename` is the `perl` version of `rename`.  It's the `rename` I know and use.)

   Then adding to your path is via:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH":"$HOME"/bin.windows_exe
   ```

Edit:  Apparently OP wanted a setup script.  After it was rejected here (which I agreed with, it was a bit simplistic), OP posted it as his own answer and move the check there, so I wrote my own.  I tried to conform to version 7 unix so it would be compatible with any Bourne shell derivative.

It includes options to set the output directory, the extension list, be verbose or quiet, to dryrun, and to remove the links.  It is careful never to overwrite existing things, except that it will replace a broken link.

The extension list and default output directory at the top can edited, as can the list of default windows directories to link to at the bottom.  (For the later, I assumed the MS-Windows drive was mounted at `/windows`.)  You could consider adding any directory in your MS-Windows path to this list.

```
#!/bin/sh

exts='exe bat cmd com vbs vbe js jse wsf wsh msc'
output_directory="$HOME/.windows_binaries"

quiet=false
verbose=false
dryrun=false
remove=false
debug=false


usage() {
    echo "`basename "$0"`" '<options>' '[<windows_directories>]'
    echo '   -d dir        Specify the output directory'
    echo '   -e ext        Add a windows extension, like "exe"'
    echo '   -E            Clear the list of extensions'
    echo '   -v, --verbose Verbose (report normal changes)'
    echo '   -q, --quiet   Quiet (don'"'"'t report errors)'
    echo '   -n, --dryrun  Do not make any changes'
    echo '   --remove      Remove links that would otherwise be made'
    (
        echo 'If no windows directories are specified,'
        echo 'everything in the PATH is done implicitly.'
        echo 'For Cygwin'
        echo 'or Microsoft'"'"'s "Windows Subsystem for Linux",'
        echo 'it is assumed'
        echo 'that PATH has been translated to Unix conventions.'
    ) | fmt
    exit 2
}

add_link() {
    $debug && echo consider "$1" "$2"
    if test -h "$2" 
    then
        # here, the target already exists, and is a link
        oldlink="`readlink "$2"`"
        if test "$1" = "$oldlink"
        then
            if $remove
            then
                $verbose && echo remove "$2"
                $dryrun || rm "$2"
            fi
        else
            if $remove
            then
                :
            else
                if test ! -e "$2"
                then
                    # old link broken, replace it
                    $dryrun || rm "$2"
                    $dryrun || ln -s "$1" "$2"
                    $verbose && echo replace broken "$2" as "$1"
                else
                    $quiet || echo "$2" already links to "$oldlink" -- not changing it to "$1"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    elif $remove
    then
        :
    elif test -e "$2" 
    then
        # here, the target already exists
        $quiet || echo Not replacing file "$2"
    else
        # here, the target does not exist
        $dryrun || ln -s "$1" "$2" 
        $verbose && echo link "$2" as "$1"
    fi

}

add_directory() {
    dir="$1"
    case "$dir" in 
        */) dir="` expr "$dir" : '\(*\)/' `" ;;
    esac
    $debug && echo consider "$1"

    for ext in $exts
    do
        for path in "$dir"/*."$ext"
        do
            # wildcards in bourne shell always return something, even if it is just the wildcard
            if test -f "$path" 
            then
                fn=`basename "$path" ."$ext"`
                add_link "$path" "$output_directory"/"$fn"
            fi
        done
    done
}

## Can't use getopt because it doesn't handle spaces, and windows directories
## are notorious for having spaces.  Can't use getopts as it is too recent.

have_dirs=
mode=
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$mode":"$arg" in
        :-d) mode=-d ;;
        :-d*) output_directory="`expr "$arg" : "-d\(*\)"`" ;;
        -d:*) output_directory="$arg" mode= ;;
        :-e) mode=-e ;;
        :-e*) exts="$exts `expr "$arg" : "-d\(*\)"`" ;;
        -e:*) exts="$exts $arg" mode= ;;
        :-E) exts="" ;;
        :-q) quiet=true ;;
        :--quiet) quiet=true ;;
        :-v) verbose=true ;;
        :--verbose) verbose=true ;;
        :-n) dryrun=true ;;
        :--dryrun) dryrun=true ;;
        :--remove) remove=true ;;
        :-*) echo Bad option "$arg" ; usage ;;
        :*)
            if test -d "$arg"
            then
                have_dirs=true
            else
                echo Argument "$arg" is not a directory 
                usage
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done

if test -z "$exts"
then
    echo No extensions specified '(and you cleared the list)'
    usage
fi

if test ! -d "$output_directory"
then
    if $remove
    then
        echo Nothing to do
        exit 0
    fi

    mkdir "$output_directory"
    $verbose && echo made directory "$output_directory"
fi

if test -n "$have_dirs"
then
    mode=
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        case "$mode":"$arg" in
            :-[de]) mode=$arg ;;
            :-[de]*) ;;
            -[de]:*) mode= ;;
            :-[Eqvn]) ;;
            :--quiet) ;;
            :--verbose) ;;
            :--dryrun) ;;
            :--remove) ;;
            :*) add_directory "$arg" ;;
        esac
    done

else
    # Do all the directories in the path.  
    IFS0="$IFS"
    IFS=:
    for pdir in $PATH
    do
        IFS="$IFS0"
        add_directory "$pdir"
    done
fi

$remove && rmdir "$output_directory" 2>/dev/null
$verbose && test ! -d "$output_directory" && echo remove directory "$output_directory"
```

Edit: revised script to use the PATH variable.  It is implicit in OP's question that he has already got all the windows executable directories he wants to use in the path.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help! I was going to do this, but recently I got another way which handles the case if new executables add-in to the binaries. in the solution posted above :)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu The advantage to the symlink over all the other methods is that it works from any shell, or other means of executing a program, without any other setup (beyond PATH, which inherits).  If you are concerned about being "up to date", I would make a cron job to update the links directory.  With care, you could even make the symlinks in /usr/bin

Comment: Thanks, I have proposed an edit to your original answer, I've created a script which creates missing executables that can be indexed from the `$PATH` with windows executable pattern (extensions). You can accep the edit if you like and you can always make it more optimized if you like to :)

Comment: Sorry, but this does not add directories which are in path but not at those static directories, if for example anything is in ProgramFiles such as notepad++ or java, symlink won't be created. My script uses `$command` variable which indexes all the commands available in the shell through Path of WSL as well as Path of Windows environment variable. Thanks for writing long script, appreciate its flexibility as well :)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu  Unix does not have access to the MS Windows path.  If you are running in cygwin, then you are in the wrong forum, and I think it will add the extensions for your anyway.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu  I missed that implicit in your question is that you already have all the windows directories listed in $PATH.  script revised.

Comment: Thinking about it, there might be performance issues in symbolic links for Windows.  (I know cygwin had to implement them as "shortcuts".  If your home directory is on NTFS (or some FAT), an alternative would be to make the script generate a stub script to invoke the right program.  (Of course, this will screw up the parameter passing.)

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias in your `.zshrc`.

```
alias docker='docker.exe'
```

Afterwards, `source` it and you're good to go. I'd consider doing this only for the executables you require. After all, you might want to run the linux `ping` instead of `ping.exe`.

Comment: Doing this for all the commands is what I was not trying to do, anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a bunch of aliases on shell startup. Please consider the dangers associated with this! So personally, I would not consider this an ideal solution.

Add to `.zshrc`

```
for command in $( IFS=':' ; find $PATH -executable -type f ) do
  if [[ $(basename $command .exe) != $(basename $command) ]] ; then
    alias $(basename $command .exe)=$command
  fi
done
```

(To be honest, I am not sure if you should replace e.g. `find` by `find.exe`, here.)

**DANGERS**

1. Conflicting aliases you set earlier. Best to execute before these aliases are set. Typical examples would be e.g. `alias rm='rm -i'`. Also pay attention whether these standard safety measures refer to `rm.exe` or `rm`!
2. `$PATH` is read front to back and the first matching command is taken. E.g. if you have a local `~/.my_executables/` in your `$PATH` and use an identical command name there to override a standard command, the above will change this. In that case e.g. pipe the `find`-results though `tac` to maintain the proper order.
3. Probably more not coming to my mind right now.

Answer (score 1):

use the hash builtin.

```
rehash() {
  hash -f
  local c
  for c in ${commands[(I)*.exe]}; hash ${c:r}=$commands[$c]
}
rehash
```

overriding the rehash built-in; which is shorthand for `hash -f`, so even when the `rehash` style is set to true, the list is rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

For bash version of `command_not_found_handler`, see https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2003#issuecomment-618655416

```bsh
command_not_found_handle()
{
   cmd=$1
   shift
   args=( "$@" )

   saveIFS="$IFS"
   IFS=:
   for dir in $PATH; do
      for executable in "$dir/$cmd.exe" "$dir/$cmd.com" "$dir/$cmd.bat"; do
         if [ -x $executable ]; then
            IFS="$saveIFS"
            "$executable" "${args[@]}"
            return
         fi
      done
   done

   IFS="$saveIFS"
   if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
      /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$cmd" "${args[@]}"
      return $?
   elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
      /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1" "${args[@]}"
      return $?
   else                                                                                                                                            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$cmd" >&2                                                                                                  return 127
   fi
}

export -f command_not_found_handle
```